# MATLAB - Arduino Serial Communication

Tags: matlab, serialization, arduino

I want to send an integer from MATLAB to the Arduino. I want the integer to be sent back and displayed in MATLAB. Sometimes nothing is displayed on MATLAB and other times wrong integers like -457 are displayed. I would appreciate it if someone can read the following codes. If there are simpler methods to approach this problem please let me know. Thanks.

MATLAB code:

```
s = serial('/dev/tty.KeySerial1')
set(s,'DataBits',8);
set(s,'StopBits',1);
set(s,'BaudRate',9600);
set(s,'Parity','none');
fopen(s);
a='b';
while (a~='a');
    a=fread(s,1,'uchar');
end 
if (a=='a')
    disp('serial read');
end 
fprintf(s,'%c','a');
mbox= msgbox('serial com set up complete'); uiwait(mbox);
fprintf(s, '%d\n', 589367);
fscanf(s,'%s')
```

Arduino sketch:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // check serial communication 
  Serial.println('a');
  char a='b';
  while (a !='a')
  { a=Serial.read();
  }

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(Serial.available()==0); 
  int val=Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.print("integer received: ");
  Serial.println(val);
}
```

Comment: For the "_wrong integer_" problem, I would first suggest to refine your communication code until `uint8` values (single byte) are properly transmitted and received. This will avoid all the problems which can be caused by endianness. Once that works, then you can try to pass larger integers (16/32/64 bits) and validate or correct the byte order.

Comment: As for the communication shema, on the Matlab side I would use the [`BytesAvailableFcn`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bytesavailablefcn.html) and attach code to the callback instead of using a `while` loop.